# Is this a common way to list items?

Tags: punctuation

The original sentence:

He must, for example, perceive an egg **as a simple single solid shape**, quite apart from its significance as food, or from the literary idea that it will become a bird. And so **with solids** such as a shell, a nut, a plum, a pear, a tadpole, a mushroom, a mountain peak, a kidney, a carrot, a tree-trunk, a bird, a bud, a lark, a ladybird, **a bulrush, a bone**.

I understand that the second sentence is an omitted version. It may be like this if fully spelled out:

He must, for example, perceive an egg as a simple single solid shape, quite apart from its significance as food, or from the literary idea that it will become a bird. And so **(does he)** **with solids** such as a shell, a nut, a plum, a pear, a tadpole, a mushroom, a mountain peak, a kidney, a carrot, a tree-trunk, a bird, a bud, a lark, a ladybird, a bulrush, a bone.

My two questions are:

1. Is it better to add ‘other’ before 'solids' in the 2nd sentence, making it as: ... And so with **other** solids such as a shell...?
2. I notice there are no 'and','or' or other symbols or words to signal the end of the listing. Is this style common for listing multiple items?

Comment: I think you mean **elided** rather than **omitted**. And there isn't really a parallel structure that could be added back in to give a simple elision—although the *idea* is also perceiving the (additional?) solids as simple single solid shapes. Actually spelling that out would involve some rephrasing rather than insertion. You're right that there should be ***or*** *a bone* at the end. Stylistically, it would also be better if the indefinite article were only used in front of the *first* list item. It's impossible to say if *other* should be used, because it's not clear what the meaning is.

Comment: It’s fine imho. Your suggestions would ruin it. If, as it appears, you are learning English, you are on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it:

> And so **he does** with **other** solids, such as a shell, nut, plum,
>   pear, tadpole, mushroom, mountain peak, kidney, carrot, tree-trunk,
>   bird, bud, lark, ladybird, bulrush **or (and)** bone.

So, you need to include:

- "He does," because without the verb, it's not a sentence
- "Other," because you specifically mention the egg is solid, so there are other solids
- Comma before "such"  to separate the non-defining clause
- "Or" or "and" before the last item, because this is the common way to list items

You can exclude "a" before each item, except before the first. You don't need a comma before the last "or" or "and."

You could join the two sentences with a semicolon; in this case, you can omit "he does." You can keep all the "a's" to make an emphasis on each item. You can omit "or" or"and" at the end. This way, it sounds more "dramatic." This is how you could write it in a story, rather than just in "a report."

> He must, for example, perceive an egg as a simple single solid shape,
>   quite apart from its significance as food, or from the literary idea
>   that it will become a bird; and so with **other** solids, such as a shell,
>   a nut, a plum, a pear, a tadpole, a mushroom, a mountain peak, a
>   kidney, a carrot, a tree-trunk, a bird, a bud, a lark, a ladybird, a
>   bulrush, a bone.